# CKEditor problem with text insertion from Excel

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

When you paste text from Excel into ckeditor 5, the editor formats its styles. Despite the fact that when Excel is closed, the text is inserted well (the second screen, without formatting), but when it is open it is not (the first screen).

Excel copies its styles to the clipboard, and ckeditor 5 chooses to paste the style that is convenient for it. How to avoid text formatting?

Without the PasteFromOffice plugin and without shift + crtl + v.
More precisely, how could one intuitively press crtl + v, and the text would be inserted without formatting?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJZMQ.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tn3p6.png)